# How to set automatic height of static cell in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am using IB and storyboard and I defined `UITableViewController`. There I defined three **static** cells. The first two should have a given height but the last one should automatically fill the remaining space (anchor to the bottom of the view). How can I achieve this? I can use autolayout for the controls **inside** the cell but it is greyed out for the cell itself.

The best solution would be to do this from IB but programmatic solutions are also welcomed.

**EDIT:**

This is how it looks in my storyboard (colors are for visualizing separate controls, each control has required constraints):
[image: Storyboard view controller]

And after launching:
[image: Simulator view]
Note that the text view ends below the bottom of the screen.

I forgot to mention that I target iOS 7.0+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{

    if indexPath.row == 0 { 
        return firstRowHeight
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 { 
        return secondRowHeight 
    }
    else { 
        return tableView.frame.size.height - firstRowHeight - secondRowHeight 
    }
}
```

The only thing that may be a problem is that this method is going to run before the view sets the tableView height

Comment: This is the best option as for now. However, I need to subtract 63 pixels more for the third row, maybe that's for the navigation bar?

Comment: So 63 (well, actually 64) is the height of navigation bar + height of status bar. Kind of strange to me that `tableView` height does contain them…

Comment: normally you should`t subtract the nav. bar height. Use view debugging to see what is the actual tableView height.

Answer (score 77):

You can actually use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` with static cells. Design your static cells per usual and manually set your cells as dynamic heights by adding

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 240 // Something reasonable to help ios render your cells
```

Now override the `heightForRow` delegate

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

The only other caveat I noticed with this technique is that you must use `NSAutolayout` to create a constraint to the bottom container (the `UITableViewCell`'s container). So let's say you have a container inside the cell's contentView that will have a dynamic height, for this to render properly you need to create a bottom space constraint.

If you have some static cells that do have fixed heights I recommend returning that size by switching on row in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`

Comment: Using Autolayout is not a caveat, it's a feature!

Comment: Works great for me. I've also implemented `tableView.reloadData()` so that my cell height gets recalculated when I change the content in this static cell.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect very true, I guess i just meant "don't forget" your bottom constraint

Comment: After setting `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight`, why does one _still_ need to implement the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @MrRogers i guess because you could have set custom height for some cells, and default implementation overrides delegate method to use these heights

Comment: @MrRogers Likely because `UITableViewController` already implements it. You're overriding it here.

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to override heightForRowAtIndexPath! Otherwise it will not display correctly from my experiences

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I covered this in a blog post using a static table view and setting the cell heights using auto layout. The cells are all defined in interface builder.

You have to enable the automatic cell heights in code but that's only a couple lines.

I show everything including IB and code.

Take a look

http://www.oliverfoggin.com/using-a-static-uitableview-as-a-layout-device/

Comment: This is how it looks when I set constraints and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for height: [link](http://i.imgur.com/4Xj3lIn.png?1) (refer to updated question for reference). I also forgot to mention that I target iOS 7.0+.

Answer (score 3):

If the whole tableview cell height is dynamic then you can try this

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 240
```

or a tableview needs some fixed height cell & some dynamic height cell the you can checkout the answer
[Dynamic & static tableview cell height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492940/5980454)

Hope it helps.

Comment: In static cell, this doesn't work. But the delegate for `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` works well, due to `UITableViewController` has it's own implementation about how to get the height of cell.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan Romanchuk's answer is great. I have a tip that may help beginner like myself.

Since this is a static cell case, you might be inclined to use `IBOutlet` for every dynamic field. Setting values in say `UILabel` outside `tableView` load cycle will not have the new height considered.

To allow the dynamic height to work, you can assign values in overridden `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate so that autolayout can pick up the new height. Call `tableView.reloadData()` when you want to update the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from IB and using the Autolayout

But using programatically,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Using this method u can check for the indexpath.row. And using this return the different height.

Comment: Of course I know that method but the question is what should I return for the third row…

Answer (score 0):

For static (non-data-driven) height, you can just dequeue the cell once and store the height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSNumber *height;
    if (!height) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
        height = @(cell.bounds.size.height);
    }
    return [height floatValue];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this could help me…