# Some tableview cells with dynamic height, other with fixed height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, row-height

I have a tableview. I want some tableview cells with dynamic height while other cells with the fixed height. For dynamic height, I used following lines in my viewDidLoad view controller delegate.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

what will be the efficient way to have fixed heighted cells and self sizing cells in one tableview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3**

You can retrun dynamic & static cell height in a tableview by doing this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 120.0 // for static cell height
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension // for dynamic cell height
    }
}
```

You have to implement another tableview estimatedHeightForRowAt method like that

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 120.0
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set label lineNumbers to 0 & lineBreakMode which label will expand dynamically & most importantly don't set the label height fixed.

Comment: is it compulsory to implement delegate method "estimatedHeightForRowAt" ?

Comment: First i tried without it & the result is not which i expected. i mean cell height is not expanding at all. Afterwards i tried with it & get the expected result which i wanted. I face same kind of problem & i solved it in this way.

Comment: Its a too late response though. Did you find any better solution ? If you have then feel free to share.

Comment: ok thanks for the response! I will try it and will let you know :)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

You can use the `indexPath` from this function to return fixed height for certain rows and dynamic height for others.

```
// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Swift 5
UITableView.automaticDimension

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, indexPath.row = 0 and 1  contains static height and dynamic height respectively, then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
     if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 120
     } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     }
}
```